# Powershell - If Folder Exists, Increment Folder Name

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to see if a folder exists, and if it does, add an increment to the folder name, like this.

FolderName

- If FolderName exists, name the folder FolderName_1
- If FolderName_1 exists, name the folder FolderName_2

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work.

```
$i = 1
if (Test-Path -Path $FolderName) {
    $FolderName  = $FolderName + '_'+ $i
    $i++
 } 
 else {
}
```

I know I am missing logic, just not sure how to make this work.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For a *robust* solution you must examine all currently existing folders that match the name pattern and extract the *highest* embedded number from them, then add 1 to that number:

```bash
# Get the highest number embedded in the names of any existing folders.
$highestExistingNum = 
  Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction Ignore -Directory $FolderName, $FolderName_* |
  ForEach-Object { if ($_.Name -match '_(\d+)$') { [int] $Matches.1 } else { 0 } }
  Sort-Object -Descending |
  Select-Object -First 1

if ($null -ne $highestExistingNum) { # At least 1 preexisting folder?
  $FolderName = $FolderName + '_' + (1 + $highestExistingNum)
}
```

Note:

- If you expect more than 10 folders, consider zero-padding the embedded numbers, so that their `Get-ChildItem` output order reflects the embedded numbers; e.g., for 3-digit `0` padding (e.g., `001`), use: `(1 + $highestExistingNum).ToString('D3')`
- The [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call finds all existing folders that fit the original name and the name pattern, if any; the `-Directory` switch limits processing to folders (directories only)

  - Note: If *no* existing folders are found, the whole pipeline outputs nothing. This case is later detected by comparing the value of `$highestExistingNum` to `$null`.
- The [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call:

  - uses the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator with a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) to see if a given folder name ends with (`$`) a `_` followed by one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`), and captures (`(...)`) the latter.
  - accesses the captured string of digits via the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) and converts it to an integer (`[int]`).
  - if the folder name doesn't end in `_` followed by a number, `0` is returned.
- [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) sorts the resulting integers in descending order (`-Descending`), i.e. the highest number is output first.
- [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) is used to select only that highest number `-First 1`.

  - Note: In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you can streamline the above by using `-Top 1` with `Sort-Object` (i.e. `Sort-Object -Descending -Top 1`), which obviates the need for the `Select-Object` call.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the use of `Rename-Item`, as well as some extra logic for detecting/updating the `_i` part:

```
$FolderName = 'foo'
$Target = "C:\"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Directory `
| Where-Object { $_.Name -match "$FolderName`_(\d+)|$FolderName"} `
| ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -match "$FolderName`_(\d+)"){
    $NewName = $FolderName + "_$([int]$matches[1] + 1)"
  } else {
    $NewName = $FolderName + '_1'
  }
  $OldName = $_.FullName
  $NewName = Join-Path $Target $NewName
  Write-Host "Found '$($_.FullName)', renaming to '$NewName'"
  Rename-Item -Path $OldName -NewName $NewName
}
```

To elaborate: `$FolderName` is presumably a string, but we want to interact with a file object. We use the `Rename-Item` cmdlet to do so, *using* the string path. We also use a simple regex to account for the `_i` counter.

Answer (score 0):

You're quite close, but you need to use another variable to store the 'base name' of your directory: otherwise you're adding _1 and then adding _2 on top of that (getting something_1_2), instead of adding _2 *instead of* _1.

Something like this:

```
$BaseName = 'MyDir'
$FullName = $BaseName
$i = 0
while (Test-Path $FullName)
{
  $FullName = "$BaseName_$i"
  $i++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a [`while` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_while) as follows:

```
$i = 0
$Suffix=''
while (Test-Path -Path "$FolderName$Suffix" -PathType Container) {
    $i++
    $suffix="_$i"
}
$FolderName  = "$FolderName$Suffix"
$FolderName
```

Supposing the following scenario:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

> ```
> folder
> folder_1
> folder_2
> ```

then (a folder exists, script returns a new name):

```
$FolderName = 'folder'
D:\PShell\SO\76583976.ps1
```

> ```
> folder_3
> ```

or (a folder does not exist, script returns the same name):

```
$FolderName = 'anotherfolder'
D:\PShell\SO\76583976.ps1
```

> ```
> anotherfolder
> ```